# How do I remove duplicate git remotes from local ist?

Tags: git, git-remote

I was playing around with pushing the same project folder to different repos (GitHub and GitLab) and ended up renaming it into a bunch of different names.

Now how do I remove remotes with name like 'upstream' and 'origin' from my list generated when I use `git branch -a`?

WHAT A MESS OF A LIST: [image: screenshot showing many branches]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to add, update, or remove any given *remote*, you use the `git remote` command.  The default action for `git remote` is to list the current set of remotes, so:

```
git remote
```

should list:

```
GitHub
GitLab
origin
upstream
```

given the set of *remote-tracking names*.  To remove all but, say, `origin`, you could use:

```
git remote remove GitHub
git remote remove GitLab
git remote remove upstream
```

Note that `git remote remove` can only remove one remote at a time, so if you have a long list of remotes to remove, you might use a shell loop:

```
for i in GitHub GitLab upstream; do git remote remove $i; done
```

(assuming you are using sh or bash or anything compatible with those).

Note that `git remote remove` also removes the corresponding *remote-tracking names*.  (Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, but I find the word *branch* here to be more confusing than helpful, so I recommend deleting it from the phrase.)

Comment: I did just that it correctly shows the 2 remotes I want to push to. However I did that by using `git config --global -e` to edit the manually (something I googled before posting question here).

Problem is when I use `git branch -a` the list still shows old names that I want to remove like origin or upstream.

Is there anyway to flush/reset that branch list from my local shell?

Comment: I also found thing like using `git branch -d -r <remote-branch>` and it does indeed remove one branch at a time. But that's going to be a chore to do it manually.

Comment: Unfortunately once you've deleted the remote, you have to work harder to clean up. Probably the easiest is to re-add and then re-delete the same remote. An alternative (but still more work) is to use a shell loop to run the `git branch -d -r` command.

Comment: OMG that sucks! But thanks a lot for clarifying it all!

Comment: Incidentally—not that it's all that useful at this point as a loop of `git remote add $i .; git remote remove $i` commands will be faster—Git provides a so-called *plumbing command*, meant for use in writing scripts to provide new Git tools, called `git for-each-ref` that lets you write a remote-tracking-name-deleter script. (Note: the `git remote add $i .` trick is to fake the URL, as Git doesn't actually *use* the URL when adding and then deleting the remote.)

Comment: This is very cool, thank you very much! I will use the shell loop in the future! Imagine writing code and still having to delete stuff manually... 